# Data between start time stamp and end time stamp at 5 minutes Interval in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am retrieving data between my start time stamp and end time stamp at every 5 minutes interval but not getting results as required this is my query

```
CREATE TABLE table_1
(
  timestamp_col text
)

INSERT INTO table_1(
            timestamp_col)
    VALUES ('04-01-2016 10:00:00'),('04-01-2016 10:01:00'),('04-01-2016 10:02:00'),('04-01-2016 10:03:00')
    ,('04-01-2016 10:04:00'),('04-01-2016 10:05:00'),('04-01-2016 10:06:00'),('04-01-2016 10:07:00')
    ,('04-01-2016 10:08:00'),('04-01-2016 10:09:00'),('04-01-2016 10:00:00'),('04-01-2016 10:10:00')
    ,('04-01-2016 10:11:00'),('04-01-2016 10:12:00'),('04-01-2016 10:13:00'),('04-01-2016 10:14:00')
    ,('04-01-2016 10:15:00');

SELECT 
    to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' from timestamp_col::timestamp without time zone) / 300 )) * 300) 
    AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' as interval_alias
    FROM table_1 Where timestamp_col::timestamp without time zone
    Between '04-01-2016 10:02:00' AND '04-01-2016 10:15:00'
    GROUP BY interval_alias

2016-01-04 10:00:00
2016-01-04 10:05:00
2016-01-04 10:10:00
2016-01-04 10:15:00
```

Required Output is

```
2016-01-04 10:02:00
2016-01-04 10:07:00
2016-01-04 10:12:00
```

Suppose my first record between "04-01-2016 10:11:11" and "04-01-2016 12:10:30" is 04-01-2016 10:12:11 
and my interval is 5 minutes then it should show record of time stamp 04-01-2016 10:12:11 + 5 minutes i.e of 04-01-2016 10:17:11 if present please help guys

Comment: I think the problem is where you are dividing by 5 minutes and then multiplying back by 5 minutes.  This is essentially normalising everything to the nearest 5 minute interval.  EG 1970-01-01 00:02:00  would become 1970-01-01 00:00:00.  I know this isn't an answer but maybe of help, still scratching my head for an answer

Comment: I am also scratching my head for the query.

Comment: I don't like the way it is modifying the data stored in the table before the where.  It will add a lot more processing time (especially as data set grows).

Comment: have you resolved at your side  ?

Comment: Yes, and just posted the answer.  Hope it works for you, you may want to add in the computation of the offset to make it easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Your current statement is normalizing your source data to 5 minute intervals, if you remove the where portion of the query you will see this:

```
   interval_alias
---------------------
 2016-01-04 10:00:00
 2016-01-04 10:00:00
 2016-01-04 10:00:00
 2016-01-04 10:00:00
 2016-01-04 10:00:00
 2016-01-04 10:05:00
 2016-01-04 10:05:00
 2016-01-04 10:05:00
 2016-01-04 10:05:00
 2016-01-04 10:05:00
 2016-01-04 10:00:00
 2016-01-04 10:10:00
 2016-01-04 10:10:00
 2016-01-04 10:10:00
 2016-01-04 10:10:00
 2016-01-04 10:10:00
 2016-01-04 10:15:00
```

So this will be adding extra load as well as destroying your source data before the actual where portion of the query.  You need to be making this calculation in the where portion of your query.  This will have the advantage of only working on the subset of the source data as well as allowing you to still have the original unmodified data.

You also need to calculate the offset from the normalized value to your desired start value.  In this case it is just 120 seconds.  So hard coding this in (to save on my typing :) ) we get:

```
SELECT 
    timestamp_col 
    FROM table_1 Where timestamp_col::timestamp without time zone
    Between '04-01-2016 10:02:00' AND '04-01-2016 10:15:00'
    AND to_timestamp(floor(extract('epoch' from timestamp_col::timestamp without time zone))) = to_timestamp((floor(extract('epoch' from timestamp_col::timestamp without time zone) / 300 ) *300) +120)
    order by timestamp_col;
```

and the results:

```
    timestamp_col
---------------------
 04-01-2016 10:02:00
 04-01-2016 10:07:00
 04-01-2016 10:12:00
(3 rows)
```

And with the offset calculation included:

```
SELECT 
    timestamp_col 
    FROM table_1 Where timestamp_col::timestamp without time zone
    Between '04-01-2016 10:02:00' AND '04-01-2016 10:15:00'
    AND to_timestamp(floor(extract('epoch' from timestamp_col::timestamp without time zone))) = 
        to_timestamp((floor(extract('epoch' from timestamp_col::timestamp without time zone) / 300 ) *300) +
          floor(extract('epoch' from '04-01-2016 10:02:00'::timestamp without time zone)) - 
            (floor((extract('epoch' from '04-01-2016 10:02:00'::timestamp without time zone)) / 300) * 300)
        )
    order by timestamp_col;
```

Offset is simply the number of seconds from the closest older normalized time.  So 10:02:00 is 2 minutes (120 seconds) after 10:00:00.

However I think the following is a much tidier solution:

```
SELECT timestamp_col FROM table_1 
  WHERE timestamp_col::timestamp without time zone BETWEEN '04-01-2016 10:02:00' AND '04-01-2016 10:15:00'
  AND ABS((floor(extract('epoch' from '04-01-2016 10:02:00'::timestamp without time zone)) - 
    floor(extract('epoch' from timestamp_col::timestamp without time zone))))::integer % 300 = 0;
```

This calculates the difference between the start time and the time in the source data in seconds and then checks to see if the result is exactly divisible by 300 ( 5 minutes) using the modulo operator.  There is no need to calculate offsets and the SQL is (IMHO) much easier to read.

Comment: how to calculate the offset ?

Comment: Normalise the start date (divide by 5 minutes and then multiply by 5 minutes as you are doing already) then subtract that result from the actual start date.  so ('04-01-2016 10:02:00') - (('04-01-2016 10:02:00' / 300) * 300)

Comment: can we directly code it in query means calculation of offset in query itself

Comment: I can do, but the offset is just the number of seconds difference between the closest normalized 5 minute time from start of epoch.  So in the example case it is 120 seconds, as 10:02:00 is 2 minutes after 10:00:00.  It is pretty messy also.  I will add a modified version of the query to the answer.  ( I feel there is a neater way to do this also)

Comment: I have just updated the answer with a different solution which I think is a bit easier to read and simpler.  HTH

Comment: what if my start time stamp changes to 03-01-2016 12:54:47 then what will be the offset. Not getting the calculation behind the offset.I have to convert it to seconds and then perform the calculation ?

Comment: You need to use the start time in both the calculation of the offset and the between clause.  I'd suggest you look at my second solution which is much simpler.  Again you will need to specify the start time in both places you can see it in the example